# R warning() wrapper - raise to parent function

Tags: r

I have a wrapper around the in-built `warning()` function in R that basically calls `warning(sprintf(...))`:

```
warningf <- function(...)
    warning(sprintf(...))
```

This is because I use `warning(sprintf(...))` so often that I decided to make a function out of it (it's in a package I have of functions I use often).

I then use `warningf` when I write functions. i.e., instead of writing:

```
f <- function() {
    # ... do stuff
    warning(sprintf('I have %i bananas!',2))
    # ... do stuff
}
```

I write:

```
f <- function() {
    # ... do stuff
    warningf('I have %i bananas!',2)
    # ... do stuff
}
```

If I call the first `f()`, I get:

```
Warning message:
In f() : I have 2 bananas!
```

This is good - it tells me where the warning came from `f()` and what went wrong.

If I call the second `f()`, I get:

```
Warning message:
In warningf("I have %i bananas!",2) : I have 2 bananas!
```

This is not ideal - it tells me the warning was in the `warningf` function (of course, because it's the `warningf` function that calls `warning`, not `f`), masking the fact that it actually came from the `f()` function.

So my question is : Can I somehow "raise" the `warning` call so it displays the `warning in f()` message instead of the `warning in warningf` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way of dealing with this is to get a list of the environments in your calling stack, and then pasting the name of the parent frame in your warning.

You do this with the function `sys.call()` which returns an item in the call stack. You want to extract the second from last element in this list, i.e. the parent to `warningf`:

```
warningf <- function(...){
  parent.call <- sys.call(sys.nframe() - 1L)
  warning(paste("In", deparse(parent.call), ":", sprintf(...)), call.=FALSE)
}
```

Now, if I run your function:

```
> f()
Warning message:
In f() : I have 2 bananas!
```

---

Later edit : `deparse(parent.call)` converts the call to a string in the case that the `f()` function had arguments, and shows the call as it was specified (ie including arguments etc).

Comment: @richiecotton thank you for the edit. Your way is much better.

Comment: +1 -- nice answer. Even simpler would be to just use `sys.call(-1)`. (It works b/c the `which` argument to `sys.call()` represents "the number of frames to go back if negative").

Comment: Fantastic! I thought it might have something to do with going through the call stack when I looked at the `warning` code, but didn't know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I know it's old but, `sys.call(sys.nframe() - 1L)`, or `sys.call(-1)`, 
returns a **vector**, with the function name and the argument.
If you use it inside `paste()` it will raise two warnings, one from the function and one from the argument.
The answer doesn't show because `f()` has no arguments.
`sys.call(sys.nframe() - 1L)[1]` does the trick.

Comment: This is more a comment on the original answer and not an answer (also, the original answer does not raise two warnings if `f()` is called with no arguments as in the original question). Additionally, the proposed fix will only print the function name in the warning message and not the arguments (i.e. not the call). I have updated the original answer; `deparse(parent.call)` currently the appropriate way to turn a call into a string.

Comment: Good :) I hadn't enough reputation to post a comment (it's weird that you can answer but not comment). Thank you. PS it doesn't raise two warnings exactly because `f()` has no args. If you have a function with arguments the `sys.call(sys.nframe() - 1L)` produce a vector and for each therm it will raise a warning.